# READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE and READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an app using this method: `getLine1Number` from `TelephonyManager`

According to Android Documentation, this method needs `READ_PHONE_STATE` runtime permission. When I call this api without giving this permission, my app crashes. However, If I grant this app with the signature permission `READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE` and without giving the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission, the api works and the app does not crash.

Why is it the case?

Answer (score 0):

the reason is simple, some APIs in order to work read permission from the android system as they are trying to access user-private data. Android, designed as a secure OS, would grant permissions to expose such data to these APIs. Some permissions needs to be explicitly agreed upon by the user, while some only need to be registered to keep track of.

Not including these permissions in the Manifesto will cause a permission not granted error and the app will crash as your source code probably does not have logic to deal with that.

Comment: Yes but in this case, I gave another permission than the one recommended by android documentation and it works and I dont understand why it works where as it is not the appropriate permission

Comment: There has been a change in the TelephonyManager API which works by granting the READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE instead of READ_PHONE_STATE. https://source.android.com/devices/tech/config/device-identifiers